# Android - exclude audiofiles / folders from music apps / media scan

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I am streaming several audiofiles in my Android app and cache them on the sdcard
( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.tmpDir" ) and delete these files after done playing.

The problem: the audio player cached the files, shows them in the playlists and doesn't delete them, but of course can't play them because they are deleted.

I searched a lot and tried everything I found, but nothing worked.

Not working:

- adding .nomedia in folder (seems only working for images)
- the folder which the audio files are stored begins with a "."
- manual rescan of the folder after the file deletion with something like

  ```
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx,
                        new String[] { dir.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }

                });
  ```